# Split a pandas column and append the new results to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

How can I split a pandas column and append the new results to the dataframe? I also want there to be no white space.

Example of my desired output:

```
col1
Smith, John
Smith, John

col2               
Smith
Smith

col3
John
John
```

I been trying this but the lambda function is not appending the results how I want it to.

```
df_split = df1['col1'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(',')))
df1['col2']= df_split.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df1['col3']= df_split.apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

I end up getting

```
col2  col3
Smith Smith
John  John
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split(..., expand=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['col2', 'col3']] = df.col1.str.split(',\s+', expand=True); df

          col1   col2  col3
0  Smith, John  Smith  John
1  Smith, John  Smith  John
```

Comment: Thanks!  What does \s+ do?  \s is whitespace but what is the + for?

Comment: @OptimusPrime In case you have more than one whitespace (preemptive strip) :)

Comment: what does expand=True do?

Comment: @OptimusPrime Will put each split item in its own column.

Answer (score 4):

We can use [Series.str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [157]: df[['col2','col3']] = df['col1'].str.extract('(\w+),\s*(\w+)', expand=True)

In [158]: df
Out[158]:
                 col1        col2   col3
0         Smith, John       Smith   John
1         Smith, John       Smith   John
2  Mustermann,    Max  Mustermann    Max
3          Last,First        Last  First
```

[`(\w+),\s*(\w+)` is a RegEx (Regular Expression) explained here](https://regex101.com/r/WU5qiv/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store first string after split, then use following

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.split(',', 1).str[0] 

          col1   col2
0  Smith, John  Smith  
1  Smith, John  Smith
```